# TCP reader losing some data

Tags: c#, tcp

I have written this simple code to read data from tcp server:

```
         TcpClient myTcpClient = null;
        NetworkStream myNetworkStream = null;

            myTcpClient = new TcpClient(pRemoteIP, pPort);
            myNetworkStream = myTcpClient.GetStream();
            myNetworkStream.ReadTimeout=4000;                              


            Byte[] bMesssage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pMessage);              


            myNetworkStream.Write(bMesssage, 0, bMesssage.Length);            

            Byte[] answer = new Byte[1024];
            string sAnswer = "";
            int offset = 0;              
            while (true)                                                      
            {                
                myNetworkStream.Read(answer, offset, 1024);                   
                sAnswer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(answer);
                if (sAnswer.Contains("#END#")) break;                         

                Array.Resize(ref answer, answer.Length + 1024);               
                offset += 1024;
            }
            int i = sAnswer.IndexOf("#END#");
            sAnswer = sAnswer.Substring(0, i);

            myNetworkStream.Close();
            myNetworkStream.Dispose() ;
            myTcpClient.Close();
```

Sometimes it works okay and reads big chunks of data sent by server but sometimes it "loses" some data and gets let's say 5000 characters instead of 25000 ones.

Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the return value of `myNetworkStream.Read` to determine how much data you actually have read. It could be as low as one byte at a time.

Probably, you should use a `StreamReader` to read strings more conveniently. Make your protocol line-based.

Comment: I approve @usr recommendations. However, not using the count returned by the Read doesn't explain losses. On the contrary, RRM may get an array larger than the expected size.

Comment: Maybe some API is not able to deal with the zero characters that this likely causes. I have no further idea about why this could be. Maybe the OP simply misdiagnosed or code is missing. Wouldn't be the first time.; For example his string will have gaps of up to 1023 characters. Maybe he is not seeing the data because of all the visual gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd keep the "buffer" at the same size and accumulate the responses until you get your "end of message" marker:

```
        Byte[] answer = new Byte[1024];
        string sAnswer = "";
        int bytesRead;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(answer, 0, answer.Length);
            ms.Write(answer, 0, bytesRead);
            sAnswer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            if (sAnswer.Contains("#END#")) break;
        }
        int i = sAnswer.IndexOf("#END#");
        sAnswer = sAnswer.Substring(0, i);
```

Comment: UTF8 can't be split at arbitrary boundaries. This will non-deterministically fail.

Comment: @usr, I'm so used to doing this with ASCII I didn't even notice the UTF8 part.  Haven't used UTF8 before, would it work better if you accumulate it in a MemoryStream like in my edit above?

Comment: I think that would work albeit with quadratic cost. I'm actually happy to see a question that does not use ASCII. Die, ASCII, die.